# Where do I upload bbPress theme when installed as WordPress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

I have a WordPress installation with bbPress plugin installed. I'm wondering where shall I upload additional WordPress themes so they will not be overwritten with bbPress upgrades?

The most straitforward guess would be wp-content/plugins/bbpress/bbp-themes/ dir, however there's an index.php inside that states:

```
<?php

/**
 * Do not put custom themes here. They will be deleted on bbPress updates.
 *
 * Keep custom bbPress themes in /wp-content/themes/
 */

?>
```

ok. I uploaded theme there but I can't find a place to switch theme. Went to Admin --> Settings --> Forums but nothing there. I even tried to create a bbp-themes dir inside of wp-content/themes and upload theme there but still no results.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add the theme to wp-content/themes/ as instructed, then choose it within the normal Appearance > Theme section.

You'll need to ensure your theme is bbPress compatible. It'll need the bbPress files and the following in the functions.php file.

```
add_theme_support( 'bbpress' );
```